# Does $\arctan(nx)$ converge in $L^{2}$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

> I want to check whether the sequence $f_{n}:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, $f_{n}(x) = \arctan(nx)$ converges in $L^{1}$ or $L^{2}$.

The pointwise limit is the discontinuous function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
            \frac{\pi}{2}&\qquad x >0\\
             0 & \qquad x =  0\\
              -\frac{\pi}{2}&\qquad x<0 \\
         \end{cases}$$

and it seems to be that if it did converge in $L^{2}$, $f_{n}$ would need to converge to $f$. I have simplified the metric down to
$$d_{1}(f_{n},f) = \left(2\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(nx)\right)^{2}dx\right)^{1/2}$$
***How do I prove or disprove that this integral goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$?***

I am not sure whether $\lim_{n\to\infty}\arctan(nx) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ is sufficient since there are functions that converge pointwise but not in $L^{2}$.

**Note:** Answers without using dominated convergence theorem or measure theory are preferred as we did not cover those topics in class.

Comment: Dominated convergence (or more particularly, bounded convergence)?

Comment: Unfortunately we didn't get up to that in class - can you see another way?

Comment: The first integral can be computed explicitly using integration by parts. For the second one I am not sure.

Comment: I tried integration by parts - how can I use the expression ? (see above)

Comment: I believe you forgot the Jacobian in your integral - the whole expression should be multiplied by $1/n$. See [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+arctan(nx)).

Comment: Thanks, fixed. I can see why it converges now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for an elementary proof, one thing you can do is use the identity $\arctan(a) = {\pi \over 2} - \arctan(1/a)$. So for the $L^2$ limit you're looking at
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(2\int_{0}^{1}\left(\arctan\bigg(\frac{1}{nx}\bigg)\right)^{2}dx\right)^{1/2}$$
Changing variables to $y = nx$ this becomes
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{2}{n}\int_{0}^{n}\left(\arctan\bigg(\frac{1}{y}\bigg)\right)^{2}dy\right)^{1/2}$$
Since $a \rightarrow a^{1 \over 2}$ is continuous this is the same as 
$$ \left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{2}{n}\int_{0}^{n}\left(\arctan\bigg(\frac{1}{y}\bigg)\right)^{2}dy\right)^{1/2}$$
Since $\arctan a \sim a$ for small $a$, the integrand shrinks like ${1 \over y^2}$ and one has 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\arctan\bigg(\frac{1}{y}\bigg)\right)^{2}dy< \infty$$
Hence the ${2 \over n}$ factor ensures the limit is zero.

In the case of the $L^1$ limit, a similar argument can be used, except the integral grows as $\log n$, so the ${2 \over n}$ factor will still result in the limit being zero.